# Отследить запуск приложения

Tags: c#, .net, процесс

Как можно отследить запуск определённого приложения, зная названия его окна, и имя исполняемого файла? У меня есть функция которая получает список процессов, но запускать её с определённым интервалов совсем не хочется (быдло-код какой-то). Знаю есть возможность через хуки но не знаю как это реализовать...

Answer (score 1):

Можно и без хуков, сделать это можно так:

```
using System;
using System.Management; // =>Project => Add Reference => System.Managemen

namespace ProcessMonitor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ManagementEventWatcher startWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(
                new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));
            startWatch.EventArrived += startWatch_EventArrived;
            startWatch.Start();
            ManagementEventWatcher stopWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(
                new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace"));
            stopWatch.EventArrived += stopWatch_EventArrived;
            stopWatch.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
            startWatch.Stop();
            stopWatch.Stop();
        }

        static void stopWatch_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Process stopped: {0}", e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value);
        }

        static void startWatch_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Process started: {0}", e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Важно!** Использование `ManagementEventWatcher` требует привилегий администратора.